# How to set default value for text and select field in admin new UI form in magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-form

I cant set any default value for textfield or select in my custom admin new ui form. In edit form it works.
I want to set system config values as default values.

Here is my Dataprovider.php

```
public function getData(){

if (isset($this->loadedData)) {
    return $this->loadedData;
}

if ($itemId)
    $items = $this->collection->getItems();

$data = $this->dataPersistor->get('form_item');
if (!empty($data)) {
   //Do something
} else {
   //When form init without any data
   // I want to setData for some field here
}

return $this->loadedData;
}
```

Here is my form.xml

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">

    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">vendor_newform.vendor_newform_data_source</item>
             <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">vendor_newform.vendor_newform_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Vendor Form</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">vendor_newform</item>
    </item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Vendor\Edit\Button\Save</item>
            <item name="delete" xsi:type="string">Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Vendor\Edit\Button\Delete</item>
            <item name="back" xsi:type="string">Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Vendor\Edit\Button\Back</item>        
        </item>
    </argument>

    <dataSource name="vendor_newform_data_source">
         <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
             <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Company\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Store\DataProvider</argument>
             <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">vendor_newform_data_source</argument>
             <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">store_details_id</argument>
             <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
             <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="module/custom/save"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
         </argument>
         <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
             </item>
         </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <fieldset name="base_fieldset">
     <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
         <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Details</item>
             <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
             <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
             <item name="openOnShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
         </item>
     </argument>

    <field name="store_details_id">
         <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                 <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                 <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                 <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store_details_id</item>
             </item>
         </argument>
    </field>

    <field name="store_name">
         <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Store Name</item>
                 <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                 <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                 <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                 <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store_name</item>
                 <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                 <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                 </item>
             </item>
         </argument>
     </field>
    <field name="store_url">
         <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
             <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Store URL</item>
                 <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                 <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                 <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                 <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store_url</item>
                 <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                 <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                 </item>                

             </item>
         </argument>
    </field>

        <field name="support_phone">
             <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Phone</item>
                     <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                     <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                     <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                     <item name="source" xsi:type="string">support_phone</item>
                     <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                     <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                     </item>                
                 </item>
             </argument>
        </field>    

    </fieldset>

</form>
```

Comment: please share your ui xml code

Comment: do you have got the solution for set system config values as default values? Please help...

Answer (score 11):

You need to add below code:

```
<item name="default" xsi:type="string">1</item>
```

For reference you can check **category_form** as below

```
    <field name="is_active">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable Category</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
```

Comment: Thanks @ Prashant .It's working.  I want this default value from system config.

Comment: @JancyAbraham you find any solution ?

Comment: No,I didn't get any solution for this

Comment: work perfect!!!

Comment: Can we dynamically set a default value?

Comment: setting a default is not right, read his question

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use system.xml configuration you can create a custom field class:

ui component:

```
<field name="field_with_configurable_default_value" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Field\ConfigurableDefaultValue">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                ...
                <item name="defaultValueConfigPath" xsi:type="string">
                  path/to/system_xml_field
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Field\ConfigurableDefaultValue:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Field;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;

class ConfigurableDefaultValue extends Field
{
    private ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;

        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $uiComponentFactory,
            $components,
            $data
        );
    }

    public function getConfiguration(): array
    {
        $config = parent::getConfiguration();
        $config['default'] = $this->scopeConfig->getValue($config['defaultValueConfigPath']);

        return $config;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can set default value via Plugin.

in your etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\DataProvider">
        <plugin name="add_default_date_to_rule"
                type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\SalesRule\Model\Rule\DataProvider" sortOrder="10" />
</type>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/SalesRule/Model/Rule/DataProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\SalesRule\Model\Rule;

class DataProvider
{
    public function afterGetData(\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\DataProvider $subject, $result)
    {
        if(empty($result)) {
            $result[null] = ['field_name' => 'your default value'];
        } 
        
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the new entry form, do the following:

```
public function getData()
{
    $data[null] = ['desired-field': 'desired-value'];
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Its not working Error unexpected ':', expecting ']'